# In Rhino js, newlines don't get converted properly

Tags: java, javascript, newline, rhino

I am experimenting with the Rhino java engine, which I want to embed in a project of mine. I made a Scriptable object scope which defines the global functions `print, printLine, log, logLine` in JavaScript. I can pull all data printed and logged by these functions by calling `pullOutput`, which returns a pair of all printed Output and logged Output. I have tested these functions and everything works as expected, but one thing.

When I give as argument for my log functions a new line, the string doesn't contain a new line char
but just "\n". For example the following code:

```
    Context context;
    try {
        context = Context.enter();
        TemplateScope scope = TemplateScope.init(context);
        context.evaluateString(scope, "log(\"test\" + \"\\n\");", "test source", 1, null);
        Pair<String, String> result = scope.pullOutput();
        System.out.println("log is: " + result.b);
    } finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
```

gives:

```
    out is: 
    log is: test\n
```

Which is obviously not what I am expecting.

The complete code is here:

https://gist.github.com/4139978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it. Another library overwrote my own rhino version with an old version and introduced this bug.